# session time out for on-line exam

Tags: php

how to set session time out for on-line exam system in php. if the student not user the screen for 5 min

```
        if(!isset($_SESSION['stdname']))
   {

   echo'<script>if (confirm("Session Timeout. Please Re-Login")){window.location = "index.php"}else{} value="Ok"</script>';

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in JavaScript:

```
echo "<script>

setTimeout(function () {
    alert('Session Timeout. Please Re-Login');
    window.location.href='index.php';
}, 300000);

</script>";
```

Hope this helps, thanks!